# python from a gps raw data output convert data into binary or ascii

Tags: python-3.x, binary, gps, ascii

So I currently work with a gnss device and I want to convert its raw data into readable data

currently my data look as follow:

```
b'\x1fb\x00\x1e\xeb\xff\xff\x14\x85\x14\x01\x00\x1e\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x87\x14\x01\x00\n'
```

I want to convert it into ascii or binary format.

Heres what it shoul look like once I make it into something readable:

0010  0D 07 2B 1C 36 00 BF FF FF FF 0B 03 0D 07 26 2B  ..+.6.¿ÿÿÿ....&+

can anyone help?

```
                   .........
```

Comment: What GPS device?

Comment: u-blox EVK-M8QCAM